# How to copy file from host to container using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

I have written a Dockerfile which looks like this

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget
```

Now I'm having a file called `abc.txt` in my host machine. How can I copy it to this container. Is there any step that I can add in Dockerfile which copy from Host to Container.

Comment: by the way, wget is already included in Ubuntu 12.04, if memory serves me

Comment: Your update and install should probably be placed on one line, see https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/#run

Comment: do you want the file in a _docker image_ or just in a _docker container_?

Answer (score 178):

Use COPY command like this:

```
COPY foo.txt /data/foo.txt
# where foo.txt is the relative path on host
# and /data/foo.txt is the absolute path in the image
```

read more details for COPY in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

An alternative would be to use ADD but this is not the best practise if you dont want to use some advanced features of ADD like decompression of tar.gz files.If you still want to use ADD command, do it like this:

```
ADD abc.txt /data/abc.txt
# where abc.txt is the relative path on host
# and /data/abc.txt is the absolute path in the image
```

read more details for ADD in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add)

Comment: Is there a possibility of doing this using the absolute path of the host machine?

Comment: Unfortunately no, you can only add files from the folder of your Dockerfile or subfolders of it. Also, soft links will not work either. This is due to the docker build process. Building starts by compressing the directory where Dockerfile resides to an archive and uses this archive to retrieve files used in ADD/COPY commands.

Comment: thanks, I wrote a shell script to automate that part. It would have been better if I could handle that through Dockerfile.

Comment: This works perfectly except when you change your Docker build context and forget about it.  If you're running `docker build` in a script check through your script to see if you changed your build context.  Once you get the source file to the right context it just works.  /facepalm

Answer (score 56):

For those who get this (terribly unclear) error:

> COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builderXXXXXXX/abc.txt: no such file or directory

There could be loads of reasons, including:

- For docker-compose users, remember that the docker-compose.yml `context` overwrites the context of the Dockerfile. Your COPY statements now need to navigate a path relative to what is defined in docker-compose.yml instead of relative to your Dockerfile.
- Trailing comments or a semicolon on the COPY line: `COPY abc.txt /app  #This won't work`
- The file is in a directory ignored by `.dockerignore` or `.gitignore` files (be wary of wildcards)
- You made a typo

Sometimes `WORKDIR /abc` followed by `COPY . xyz/` works where `COPY /abc xyz/` fails, but it's a bit ugly.

Comment: Adding to this -- if you move a Dockerfile in pycharm, it can alter the context automatically.

Comment: Ahh thanks! Found a pesky `.gitignore` that was preventing `ADD foo.zip .` in my Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks! For me the issues was `.gitignore`

Comment: For me, the WORKDIR trick did the job.

Answer (score 9):

I faced this issue, I was not able to copy zeppelin [1GB] directory into docker container and was getting issue

> COPY failed: stat
> /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder977188321/zeppelin-0.7.2-bin-all: no
> such file or directory

I am using docker Version: 17.09.0-ce and resolved the issue with the following steps.

Step 1: copy zeppelin directory [which i want to copy into docker package]into directory contain "Dockfile"

Step 2: edit Dockfile and add command [location where we want to copy]
`ADD ./zeppelin-0.7.2-bin-all /usr/local/`

Step 3: go to directory which contain DockFile and run command [alternatives also available] `docker build`

Step 4:  docker image created Successfully with logs

Step 5/9 : ADD ./zeppelin-0.7.2-bin-all /usr/local/
---> 3691c902d9fe

Step 6/9 : WORKDIR $ZEPPELIN_HOME
---> 3adacfb024d8 ....
Successfully built b67b9ea09f02

Comment: The important step here is the fact the file must be in the same folder as the Dockerfile

Answer (score 4):

I got the following error using Docker 19.03.8 on CentOS 7:

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builderXXXXXXX/abc.txt: no such file or directory
```

The **solution** for me was to build from Docker file with `docker build .` instead of `docker build - < Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 3):

you can use either the ADD command https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/add or the COPY command https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/copy

Answer (score 2):

I was able to copy a file from my host to the container within a dockerfile as such:

1. Created a folder on my c driver --> c:\docker
2. Create a test file in the same folder --> c:\docker\test.txt
3. Create a docker file in the same folder --> c:\docker\dockerfile
4. The contents of the docker file as follows,to copy a file from local host to the root of the container: 
     FROM ubuntu:16.04

   COPY test.txt /
5. Pull a copy of ubuntu from docker hub --> docker pull ubuntu:16.04
6. Build the image from the dockerfile -->  docker build -t myubuntu c:\docker\
7. Build the container from your new image myubuntu --> docker run -d -it --name myubuntucontainer myubuntu "/sbin/init"
8. Connect to the newly created container -->docker exec -it myubuntucontainer bash
9. Check if the text.txt file is in the root --> ls

You should see the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the current dir's contents, you can run:

```
docker build  -t <imagename:tag> -f- ./ < Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I had to do to copy an external nginx.conf file into the container's /etc/nginx directory on Linux.

In docker-compose.yml

```
 services:
 
   xhgui:
     build:
       # This directory is at docker/xhgui
       context: ./xhgui
       args:
         # This file is at docker/xhgui/config
         NGINX_CONFIG_FILE: ./config/nginx.conf
     image: xhgui/xhgui:latest
     restart: always
     # Not sure if this volume declaration is necessary
     volumes:
       - ../:/xhgui
```

Then in docker/xhgui/Dockerfile

```
ARG NGINX_CONFIG_FILE
COPY ${NGINX_CONFIG_FILE} /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```