# Docker: error copying file from host to container-file not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I am trying to copy a file from my host (Ubuntu 18.04) to a python container but I am having trouble copying it over. The purpose is to take my specific configuration for my default sound device and transfer it over so I don't have to do it manually later.

I've tried several variations and I am wondering if I am misunderstanding how to copy files over. I've checked the documentation and other various questions people on stackoverflow have asked regarding this like this one:

[How to copy file from host to container using Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455036/how-to-copy-file-from-host-to-container-using-dockerfile)

But I get an error when I try the traditional command:

```
docker-compose build 
...
Step 7/7 : COPY /config/.asoundrc ~/.asoundrc
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat config/.asoundrc: file does not exist
```

I don't have a docker ignore file in my root directory. My directory looks like this:

```
dejavu (root name)
-config
--.asoundrc
-docker-compose.yaml
...
```

To be clear, I want to copy the file `config/.asoundrc` from my host to the container image, specifically the directory destination as `~/.asoundrc`

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install \
    gcc nano \
    gdebi alsa-utils usbutils ffmpeg libasound-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 \
    postgresql postgresql-contrib pulseaudio -y
RUN pip install numpy scipy matplotlib pydub pyaudio psycopg2 sounddevice

WORKDIR /code
COPY /config/.asoundrc ~/.asoundrc
```

Here is the original repo, it's currently being modified from an open source project: https://github.com/datafaust/dejavu

Comment: `COPY ~/.asoundrc /config/.asoundrc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have two issues in your `COPY` command:

1. Your source path starts with a slash, it shouldn't
2. Your destination path contains a `~`, which will not be converted to the home directory, as it does in a shell script.

Try this:

```
COPY config/.asoundrc /root/.asoundrc
```

In addition, after reviewing your `docker-compose.yml`, it is clear that the *main* problem is there.

Your docker-compose file defines a build context:

```
services:
  python:
    build:
      context: ./docker/python
```

Which means this is the directory that all `COPY` commands are relative to. Since this directory only contains the `Dockerfile`, and not the requested `config/.asoundrc` file, the build failed with a clear error.

You should place each `Dockerfile` in the same directory as the application it builds. So, to fix it:

- Move the `Dockerfile` from `docker` to `dejavu`.
- Change the build context in `docker-compose.yml` from `./docker/python` to `dejavu` (also note, no leading dot needed).

Comment: No dice, I get the following error: `Step 5/8 : WORKDIR /code
 ---> Running in 6a454bd62b9d
Removing intermediate container 6a454bd62b9d
 ---> 01e08b2b84b4
Step 6/8 : COPY config/.asoundrc /root/.asoundrc
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat config/.asoundrc: file does not exist` Basically the main issue seems to be that the file does not exist which doesn't make sense

Comment: Then your question is missing some detail. The problem probably lies in the build-context definition in your `docker-compose.yml`. Can you share the most minimal docker-compose service definition?

Comment: Hey Danny, certainly. I added the link to my github repo where you will see the `docker-compose.yml` and the `dockerfile`. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Your build context is the problem. I updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for the help with this, appreciate it greatly