# How to add file to docker container?

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I work with the airflow operators and mlproject. So the pipeline looks like the following : I define airflow operator, in which I specify entry point of MLProject and parameters for the program, then it turns to MLProject file where running command is specified, so it has the following form:

```py
dq_checking = MLProjectOperator(
    task_id = 'dq_checking',
    dag = dag,
    project_name = 'my_project',
    project_version = '$VERSION',
    entry_point = 'data_validation', 
    base_image = 'my_docker_image',
    base_image_version = '0.1.1',
    hadoop_env = 'SANDBOX',
    project_parameters = {
        'tag': default_args['tag']
    },
    environment = {
        'some_environment_variable' : 'some_value'
    }
)
```

Here `MLProjectOperator` is inherited from `DockerOperator`. Then I have MLProject

```py
name: my_project
conda_env: conda.yml
entry_points:
    data_validation:
        parameters:
            tag: string
        command: >
        spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster 
        --num-executors 20 --executors-cores 4
        my_project/scoring/dq_checking.py -t {tag}
```

The question is, I need to read some files in script `dq_checking.py`. Locally they are in the same directory `my_project/scoring`. But as far as I understand in production this script is running in its own docker container and therefore there are no those files. How can I add them to the container?

Comment: check out `docker cp` to do it on the fly otherwise to do it via your dockerfile : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455036/how-to-copy-file-from-host-to-container-using-dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I should include path to files into file `MANIFEST.in` whn building up a project. Then via `--files` parameter of `spark-submit` command add it with script.